# -bash: yarn: command not found even after installing it globally

Tags: bash, macos, yarnpkg

Mac OS  10.13.6

How did I install yarn

```
npm install --global yarn
```

yarn installation path is `/Users/useName/.config/yarn`

Then ran below command

```
yarn create react-app app-name
```

This worked well, but when I'm trying to run `yarn add package_name`, it's throwing error

```
bash: yarn: command not found
```

The weird thing, after closing and opening terminal again under which I had globally ( ? ) installed yarn, the yarn command is not found.

Comment: Srrange. Could you please post the contents of your `bashrc` file.

Answer (score 13):

Just re- install using "brew install yarn" and that should solve it.

Comment: this simple solution worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Execute this on your Mac command line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH.
```

This will set the NPM PATH DIRECTORY

Answer (score 5):

try `export PATH=~/.yarn/bin:$PATH` into .profile   !**

*or*

try: If you are on the bash try adding `alias yarn=~/.yarn/bin/yarn.js`

```
We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
```

[create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

[@github ;)](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/601#issuecomment-679879139)

Try this [Stackoverflow :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40116358/15107749)

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, I've edited question and added yarn directory on Mac

Comment: Did you tried installing yarn through homebrew package manager `brew install yarn`

Comment: what does `yarn --version` says

Comment: did  you do `yarn init`

Comment: I don't want to install using *brew* but with npm way.  yarn --version just gives error message "command not found"

Comment: that's confirm that yarn is not installed **properly**

Comment: strangely after installing yarn, I could able to run yarn create react-app appName without any failure. How is that possible ? I mean 1st time installation is success and later it didn't work at all ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230012/discussion-between-vikramvi-and-ullas-kunder).

Answer (score 5):

Per this [Yarn Installation guide](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)  "The preferred way to manage Yarn is through Corepack, a new binary shipped with all Node.js releases starting from 16.10."

As of 2023 - on a Mac - for Node.js >=16.10 - this worked for me after updating node to 16.17:

```
corepack enable
```

Comment: 2 days troubleshooting this on Mac M1. Yarn "segmentation fault" in VSCode terminal, but regular Mac terminal was fine. Followed this suggestion (use the link above for details) and finally fixed!

Comment: I could kiss you right now, such an amazing fix

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `nodenv` and `yarn` is not working try a simple

$`nodenv rehash`

after that yarn should work

Answer (score 1):

Global packages won't be installed in a user account. The path you mention is for configuration. Try to find where Yarn was really installed or just try `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` (that's where Yarn is on my machine).

Comment: can you clarify how did you install yarn & which OS you've ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using MacOS 10.15.7. I installed yarn with Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

`echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc`

if you have installed yarn via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

After `npm i -g yarn` I had to manually add npm packages to my $PATH. Adding these two lines to my `~/.profile` fixed it, after restarting the Terminal the yarn command became available:

```
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
export PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
```

I found them in my `~/.bashrc` but somehow it was not executed.

Comment: Which OS are you using ? I'm on Mac and I don't see ~/.profile there.

Comment: I'm on macOS 11.2.3, I had to create `~/.profile` too